# Visual Studio for Mac add ADO.NET Entity Data Model template

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ado.net, visual-studio-mac

How would I add the ADO.NET Entity Data Model template to my WebApi project in Visual Studio for Mac?

Comment: [This](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/15786/missing-adonet-entity-data-model-template.html) is related to Windows, but might also apply in your case. See if it helps.

Comment: Very likely that you have to go back to do it in Visual Studio on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac, to add a Data Model using the DataFirst technique you need to use the scaffold command.

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database

In the above blog, this process is explained neatly.